# Should I downvote answers that ignores vital things that is not important to the actual problem?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

#### TL;DR

Are there any guidelines for when (if ever) you should downvote answers containing code which contains very bad code lines that teaches bad habits or are bad in another way, but those lines are not directly connected to the question?

---

It was hard to come up with a good title, but sometimes I see answers that contains very dangerous code, but the dangerous lines are not really relevant to the question, but they teaches bad habits.

One prime example is the use of `scanf` without checking it's return value. For all you non-C coders reading this, the statement `scanf("%d", &x)` will read an integer from standard input and store it in the variable `x`. Also, it will return the number of successful assignments. So if the above statement returns `0`, the reading failed. It is easy to see why it is dangerous not not check the return value.

Another example is in C++, which is the line `using namespace std;`. Read here why it is bad: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6699433)

So let's say that someone asks how to write a program that asks the user to enter an integer and then outputs the number of digits. A user gives this code in an answer:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    int n=0;
    do { 
        n++;
    } while(x/=10);
    printf("Number of digits: %d\n", n);
}
```

Assume that it clear from the question that the do-while loop is the only thing that is clearly connected to the problem in the question, and that the rest is just to make the code complete.

I can see five possible things to remark in this code that has nothing to do with the question, but may teach bad habits, although some are REALLY nitpicking:

1. `#include <stdio.h>` is missing (needed to use printf and scanf)
2. `fflush(stdout)` is missing (May cause "Enter an integer" to not get printed before scanf)
3. Return value of `scanf` is not tested (`x` may have any value)
4. `argc` and `argv` is never used, so the signature should be `int main()` (will trigger an unnecessary compiler warning)
5. main has no return statement (undefined behavior in C89 and earlier)

Of these, I would say that only 3 may be worth a downvote. Just for the reason that it teaches very bad habits. But are there any guidelines for how to handle this?

Of course it makes a difference if you post code like that with a comment like *"Note that this code is unsecure. I did not do any error checking whatsoever. Remember to always check the return value of `scanf`."*

Comment: I think it is a good question. Based on the earlier post, we discussed, my thought is to weigh the intent of the question. If it would distract from the point of the question, avoid becoming mired in the muck of providing all corrections. However, such points may be worth commenting on (in an answer), after addressing the focus of the post.

Comment: Instead of down-voting, why not just leave a comment underneath the answer suggesting that the author edit out the code that is considered a bad practice? If they ignore your comment, then you might choose between simply editing their answer yourself, or downvoting it, or adding a better answer of your own.

Comment: @AlexHarvey comments can be deleted at any time, especially if OP flags it as "no longer needed" after some random edit... You need to decide if you consider post bad or not - if you think post good as it is (and should not be downvoted) - you can just move on... I'm really puzzled why it is considered ok to do equivalent of "this is very bad idea, but I'll *upvote* your post as you put some efforts"

Comment: I guess you're confused about why most people are nice, @AlexeiLevenkov. A downvote communicates no information at all. It means someone doesn't like something. Could be anything from a revenge downvote to someone random on the internet having a bad day. A comment explains what the issue is so the author can fix it.